# How to revert ubuntu updates and installs to specific time?

Tags: updates, uninstall, netbeans

Title may no be clear, i want to revert all updates and installations from my ubuntu to specific time. I have two netbeans on it with different version numbers. I want to revert all updates and installations since the day i installed second netbeans.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong. But all i know ubuntu doesnt have "time machine" or "system restore" like tool. You can not revert all update that you have installed. About ur netbeans you can remove using terminal with command: sudo apt-get remove netbeans or apt-get purge netbeans